# Flask multiple optional url parameters in url separated by semicolon

Tags: flask, flask-restplus

I need accept the following url in my flask restplus app: 
*.../app/u1=abc;u2=222;u3=xx;u4=jjj*, all of them can be optional
How I need to define my route?

```
@api.route('/app/u1=<u1>;u2=<u2>;u3=<u3>;u4=<u4>')
```

Comment: if you want to make it optional you should take it as the query parameter

Comment: URL parameters are not separated by semicolons. Are you sure this is exactly what you have?

Comment: @HarshalParekh yes, it exactly what I have.